# C structure initialization before using it?

Tags: c, initialization, structure

I do not understand why i have to initialize my structure before using it, i get this error in my code, i know it works if i use pointers or if i initialize the structure members, but why it does not work in this way ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    typedef struct human{
        char name[20];
        int age;
    } student;
    void function(student ){
        printf("It's not working");
    } 
    int main(){
        student a;
        function(a); 
        return 0;
    }
```

I get this
Debug Error!
 File: Run - Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'a' is being used without being initialized. (Press Retry to debug the application)

and i do not get the message from my function on output

Comment: You're missing a parameter name in your declaration of the method `function()`.

Comment: Define "not working" please

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "this error" and "does not work".

Comment: Tell us why it is not working. Can you compile that code?

Comment: Debug Error!

File:

Run - Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'a' is being used without being initialized.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

and i do not get the message from my function on output

Comment: Change `void function(student ){` for `void function(student aStudent){`

Comment: its not working, i need to initialize a.name and a.age but if i want to use a function like void get(student a){ gets(a.name); gets(a.age);}  i need to use pointers why it is not possible to work like this ?

Comment: `gets` is not a C function ... don't even think about using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the object `a` by value to `function`. As C has *only* value-semantics, it can only copy values in this case. So, you initialise the parameter (even if your implementation doesn't care about the parameter) with an unitialised object, wich requires reading from that object. This is undefined behaviour, hence the compiler informs you that you are doing something illegal.

If you pass the object via a pointer, you still pass-by-value, but the value being copied is the pointer. Hence you don't have to read the actual value and your compiler wont complain.

Observe:

```
void flat(student s) {
  s.age = 20;
}
void ptr(student* s) {
  s->age = 20;
}
int main() {
  student s = {"Eve", 0};
  // { s.age == 0 }
  flat(s);
  // { s.age == 0 }  --- still the same, no change
  ptr(&s);
  // { s.age == 20 } --- now it has changed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get this error, because your debugger detect, that you are sending unitialized variable to the function. It doesn't know, what will you do with it inside of the function, so it warns you. You can see, that if you run program in release, no error will occur. Easiest solution for you, if you know, that you will initialize it lately to correct values, is just to initialize it, when creating `student a = {0};`